# Issue with setupActionBarWithNavController in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-fragments, kotlin-coroutines

I am creating an app with Kotlin and Android Studio. Every dependency is on it's latest version. I'm trying to customize the `app toolbar's label` with Android Jetpack Navigation component label. In my `MainActivity.kt` I have this code.

```kotlin
// MainActivity.kt

package com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        setupActionBarWithNavController(findNavController(R.id.fragment))
    }
}
```

In my `ListFragment`

```kotlin
//ListFragment.kt
package com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.fragments.list

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_list.view.*

class ListFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false)

        view.floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listFragment_to_addFragment)
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

And in my `AddFragment`

```kotlin
// AddFragment
package com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.fragments.add

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_add.view.*


class AddFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)

        view.saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_addFragment_to_listFragment)
        }
        return view
    }
}
```

My app doesn't even launch. Here's the LOGCAT Output on that error

```
2020-10-11 12:03:51.219 11162-11162/com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp, PID: 11162
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp/com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.MainActivity@6d0f1b does not have a NavController set on 2131230870
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.MainActivity@6d0f1b does not have a NavController set on 2131230870
        at androidx.navigation.Navigation.findNavController(Navigation.java:61)
        at androidx.navigation.ActivityKt.findNavController(Activity.kt:30)
        at com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:13)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

**EDIT**

Here are my Layouts
ActivityMain

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/my_nav"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_list.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.list.ListFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_add.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/addFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.add.AddFragment">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputFirstName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputLastName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Last Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputFirstName" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Age"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputLastName" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/saveButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="312dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_save_alt_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputAge" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**EDIT 2**

After adding `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` to my fragment in my main layout i have a new problem. The app loads properly but now it crashes when I click on the floatingActionButton to change fragments.

Here's my logcat output

```
2020-10-11 12:36:33.348 11853-11853/com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp, PID: 11853
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.michaelgrigoryan.roomdbapp.fragments.add.AddFragment.onCreateView(AddFragment.kt:32)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Post your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity layout use:

```
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Comment: This works but I have another error. When I click on the floatingAction Button to switch between fragments the app crashes

Comment: @michael.grigoryan It is a different kind of issue. Post a new question with your graph, fragment_list.xml layout and the full stacktrace.

Comment: Check Out the Edit 2

Answer (score 1):

First things first: You need to have visible action bar!

Go to the themes file and change the parent to:

parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).